# Access a JSON string value, undefined

Tags: json

I have this example where I am trying to access a JSON value, but I get undefined value for id.

My JSON:

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "msg": "",
    "obj": [
        {
            "remark": "test-1",
            "settings": "{\n \"clients\": [\n {\n \"id\": \"430c867306d8\",\n \"alterId\": 0\n }\n ],\n \"disableInsecureEncryption\": false\n}",
        },
        {
            "remark": "test-2",
            "settings": "{\n \"clients\": [\n {\n \"id\": \"9831d43186de\",\n \"alterId\": 0\n }\n ],\n \"disableInsecureEncryption\": false\n}",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to fetch remark and id, so I wrote:

```
const remark = data.obj[i].remark;
const settings = data.obj[i].settings.clients[0].id;
```

Note: `data` is where my data is in actual code.

Comment: `settings` is a JSON string. OP should fix the JSON and leave `settings` as a dictionary.  Should tag a language as well.

Answer (score 0):

settings should be parsed before using

```
const settings =  JSON.parse(data.obj[i].settings).clients[0].id;
```